# Webpack не поддерживает классы?

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой: объявление класса со свойством (приватным или нет - не важно)

```
'use strict';

class Mult {   value = 2;

  constructor(int) {
    this.int = int;   }

  double() {    return this.int * this.value;   } }

let val = new Mult(5);

console.log(val.double())
```

приводит к ошибке

```
    index.js:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| class Mult {
>   value = 2;
| 
|   constructor(int) {
    at eval (index.js:1)
    at Object../app/js/index.js (bundle.js:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:84
    at bundle.js:87
```

Сборка: gulp + webpack.
Что это значит?
Webpack не поддерживает классы ES6?

Comment: Webpack тут ни при чём, это ваша версия nodejs не поддерживает классы и вам нужно её обновить

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась подключением babel и плагина @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties. В webpack.config это выглядит так:

```
 module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
        }
      }
    }]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

В документации MDN по [классам](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) говорится

> Public and private field declarations are an experimental feature (stage 3) proposed at TC39, the JavaScript standards committee. Support in browsers is limited, but the feature can be used through a build step with systems like Babel.

Попробуйте обновит ваш node.js или использовать Babel

Comment: Обновился с 12.14.1 до 13.6.0 - проблема осталась. Если не собирать webpackом в chrome(79) все работает.

Comment: @artdemo ну тогда babel подключайте

Comment: Если я правильно понял, babel это библиотека для поддержки браузеров не понимающих es6. Но если я пишу только для современных движков, то babel мне не нужен? Получается либо babel+webpack либо никак?

Comment: Стрелочные функции, деструктуризация и `и вот эти вот скобки`  работают, а свойства классов нет.